# What is causing memory leak in UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uipageviewcontroller

I'm experiencing some memory leaks in a new app I'm working on. 
Memory leak starts soon after launching the app, and Xcode leaks points to SetViewControllers method in UIPageviewController, inside viewDidLoad. I haven't been able to figure out what is the exact cause.

Here's the code for the UIPageViewController:

```
import UIKit

class OnboardingPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {


    // Create viewcontroller array for pageview

    lazy var availableViewControllers: [UIViewController] = [vcOne, vcTwo, vcThree]


    lazy var vcOne: UIViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onboardingOne")

    lazy var vcTwo: UIViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onboardingTwo")

    lazy var vcThree: UIViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "onboardingThree")


    deinit{
        print("ONBOARDING PAGEVIEW DEALLOCATED")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        dataSource = self

        unowned let firstVc = availableViewControllers[0]


        setViewControllers([firstVc], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }



    // Func to create new viewController

    func newVc(_ viewControllerId: String) -> UIViewController{
    unowned let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerId)
        return vc

    }


    // UIPageviewControllerDataSource protocol funcs

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = availableViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {return nil}

        let previousVc = vcIndex - 1

        guard previousVc >= 0 else {return nil}

        guard availableViewControllers.count > previousVc else {return nil}

        return availableViewControllers[previousVc]
    }


    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = availableViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {return nil}

        let nextVc = vcIndex + 1

        guard nextVc < availableViewControllers.count else {return nil}

        guard availableViewControllers.count > nextVc else {return nil}

        return availableViewControllers[nextVc]
    }
}
```

The viewControllers are declared as lazy vars, but I originally used the newVc function to create the view controllers in the availableViewControllers array. No changes in the leak after the change.

The memory leaks increase with over 100 new ones after scrolling the pages.

The viewControllers only contain one ImageView in the storyboard per viewController.

I have another UIPageViewController later on in the app which uses the same logic, and based on the first one's behaviour, it's most likely also causing some the later leaks the app.

Edit: datasource moved to parent vc. Edit2: Datasource changed to [String]

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

//  lazy var db = Firestore.firestore()
//  lazy var uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid


// let notice = Notice()
// unowned let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

// lazy var availableViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {[newVc("onboardingOne"), newVc("onboardingTwo"), newVc("onboardingThree")]}()

var availableViewControllers: [String] = ["onboardingOne", "onboardingTwo", "onboardingThree"]

weak var pvc: UIPageViewController!



deinit {
    print("LOGINVIEW Deinit RAN")
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let pvc = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
    pvc.dataSource = self
    self.addChild(pvc)
    self.containerView.addSubview(pvc.view)

    pvc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerView.frame.width, height: containerView.frame.height)

    unowned let firstVc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: availableViewControllers[0])

    pvc.setViewControllers([firstVc], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.pvc = pvc

   // setupLoginButton()


  }

// Modify login/register Button

func setupLoginButton() {
    loginButton.layer.borderWidth = 0
    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    loginButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    loginButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 4)
    loginButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.init(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.frame = loginButton.bounds
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 25
    loginButton.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}

func newVc(_ viewControllerId: String) -> UIViewController{
    unowned let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerId)
    return vc

}

// Login/register button pressed

@IBAction func loginButtonTouched(_ sender: Any) {

  /*  if appDelegate.connected == false {

        present(notice.networkAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    else { */

    //Setup and get FirebaseUI for login/register (and set delegate)

    let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    let authViewController = authUI?.authViewController()
    authUI?.delegate = self

    // Present FirebaseUI

    present(authViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

 //   }
}


// Handle Firebase Auth result

func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {

    //Show error if one appeared

    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    // Make sure Authdataresult exists

    guard authDataResult != nil else { return }


    // Move to main screen with logged in user




}

// UIPageviewControllerDataSource protocol funcs

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let vcIndex = availableViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController.restorationIdentifier!) else {return nil}

    let previousVc = vcIndex - 1

    guard previousVc >= 0 else {return nil}

    guard availableViewControllers.count > previousVc else {return nil}

    return storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: availableViewControllers[previousVc])
}


func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let vcIndex = availableViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController.restorationIdentifier!) else {return nil}

    let nextVc = vcIndex + 1

    guard nextVc < availableViewControllers.count else {return nil}

    guard availableViewControllers.count > nextVc else {return nil}

    return storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: availableViewControllers[nextVc])
}
```

}

Comment: You are using page view controller wrong. Never keep a list of references to view controllers like that! Do not subclass UIPageViewController!

Comment: @matt Ok, can you elaborate how am I using it wrong? I originally didn't have the references, but the behaviour was the same. How would I introduce the controlling logic if I don't subclass UIPageVIewController?

Comment: @matt 'Do not subclass UIPageViewController!' Why? From the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller at the very end it says: 'This class is generally used as-is, but can also be subclassed.'

Comment: I don’t know what “introduce the controlling logic” means. Page view controllers are very simple. You act as data source and create view controllers on demand and return them when you are asked for them.

Comment: Yes but you do not know how to subclass it. You are subverting its  workings. If you want to embody common logic, embody it in a common data source class, not inside a subclass.

Comment: @matt thanks for clearing, I had the pvc already embedded in a container view, I just had the logic in the pvc subclass, I now removed the subclass and moved the datasource to the parent vc, but, there are now more memory leaks than before. Though instruments is not catching where the leaks are coming from

Comment: Well, I don't know what you're doing now, do I? Using a page view controller is very simple and it doesn't leak anything when you use it normally. Do you need an example of a simple page view controller? This is a downloadable project you can run; you'll see it doesn't leak anything: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p317pageControllerChild/ch19p626pageController/RootViewController.swift

Comment: By the way, a page view controller does cache some of its pages, so do not imagine, just because a page doesn't deinit when you page away from it, that it is leaking. The only question is what happens when you leave the entire scene and page view controller itself is torn down.

Comment: @matt yep, figured as much as at least the scrolling wouldn't work as expected without caching. Instruments are showing the number of the leaks, but now the leaks are coming so early that it doesn't capture the source, they went from 10 -> 50 after just changing the datasource and using UIPageViewController instead of subclass. Everything else that could cause leaks before the pvc have been commented out

Comment: I've shown you my code. It doesn't leak. You have not shown your new code so I don't know anything about why it does leak.

Comment: @matt Added the parent vc code as it is when the leaks appear. This is the rootVc of the project

Comment: But you didn't stop doing what I said not to do. Your `availableViewControllers` is wrong. Do not keep a list of view controllers! Look at the example I gave you. Think about how it differs from what you're doing.

Comment: @matt now I got what you meant, I changed the datasource to [String] (updated code above), but still getting over 30 leaks. Scrolling through the pageViewController doesn't cause leaks anymore though.

Comment: Well, that was presumably what the question was about, so I consider the matter closed. I suggest that you delete this question and, if you have leaks you can't track down with Instruments, ask a whole new question, giving _details_ about those leaks.